# If one is non veg for most part of his life and turns veg, what atonement can he do?

Tags: scripture, non-vegetarian

If one is non veg till much of his life as his/her parents, what atonement can he/she do?

General, non vegetarian like one who eat chicken , fish and egg then turns veg in influence of scripture or a guru Or anything. ***Person became non veg as his /her parents were.***

> He who desires to augment his own flesh by eating the flesh of other
> creatures, lives in misery in whatever species he may take his [next]
> birth." (Mahabharata, Anu.115.47)

***What is possible atonement for the person if he turns vegetarian afterwards in life ?***

[It would be better if atonement is given from smritis Or itihass granth instead of puranas(many interpolations) ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Manu Smriti 5.53. He who during a hundred years annually offers a
> horse-sacrifice, and he who entirely abstains from meat, obtain the
> same reward for their meritorious (conduct).

So, when a person who was a meat eater, gives up meat, he thereby earns the merits of performing Aswamedha Yajna annually as long s he is not eating meat.

Therefore, I don't think any additional atonement is required as the merit earned from the performance of Aswamedha Yajna is already very huge.

Comment: What will you say about :He who desires to augment his own flesh by eating the flesh of other creatures, lives in misery in whatever species he may take his [next] birth." (Mahabharata, Anu.115.47)+arya samaj translation never has meat eating /killing in ashwamedha and they translate from nirukta

Comment: The same thing is stated in Manu too .. but the point is one who gives up meat acquires the merit of performing annual Aswamedha Yajna. Not sure about what Arya Samaj says but IMO they are biased and can not be taken seriously in most cases. Aswamedha Yajna and the Vedic sacrifices are facts which no one can refute. @Hope

Comment: But how can it make sense :not to kill animals and kill animals for Godly sacrifices.

Comment: Who has created animals? It's neither me nor you. Prajapati who has created animals said animals are created for sacrifices. Herbs,animals which are killed in sacrifices attain higher abodes. Killing outside of sacrifices is of course never prescribed @Hope

Comment: 5.39. Svayambhu (the Self-existent) himself created animals for the sake of sacrifices; sacrifices (have been
instituted) for the good of this whole (world); hence the slaughtering (of beasts) for sacrifices is not slaughtering
(in the ordinary sense of the word) @Hope

Comment: 5.40. Herbs, trees, cattle, birds, and (other) animals that have been destroyed for sacrifices, receive (being
reborn) higher existences. @Hope